# How do I capture and use a JSON request I know will be incorrectly formatted?

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm trying to work up a proof of concept wherein I receive a POST request that then triggers a different POST request. I thought I would setup a nodejs/express server to test this, but the POST request I'm receiving has Content-Type application/json and a body with data that is (I believe) incorrectly formatted JSON.

e.g. `{ something: "data" }`

I can't change this request, and I just need to use the data to send a different request, but Node throws an error: "Unexpected token in json at position" everytime it receives the request. I'm sure this is because the content is marked as JSON, but the body isn't formatted correctly; I just don't know enough about node/express to know how to deal with it. I looked at bodyParser and writing my own middleware function, but I could really use some direction.

Following DamiToma's advice I added error handling, but for some reason the middleware isn't being called:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = router;

router.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Error handling middleware called...");
    if(error instanceof SyntaxError) {
            switch(error.type) {
            case 'entity.parse.failed':
                // JSON is incorrect
                console.log('JSON is incorrect');
                break;
            default:
                // other error
                break;
        }

        res.status(400).end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

// POST
router.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    res.send('POST');
    console.log(req.body);

});
```

If I put the error handling on the app rather than router, it works, I'm just not sure why it doesn't apply when I put in on the router.

Comment: Where is the content type defined as JSON? I assumed the request was rejected by express due to incorrect formatting, but were you talking about a `JSON.parse` throwing an error somewhere instead? I believe you need `router.use(express.json())` at the top to throw the validation error in the middleware.

Comment: In the request (which I'm receiving from a system I don't have any control over) the Content-Type is application/JSON, but when receiving a request (sent to a postman mock server just to view it) the body is { tag: "value"}. There are no quotes around the tag. When I try and view the req.body from the node server it just shows an empty body; which, I assume is because it can't parse the bad json. I know the request is going to always be that way, so if I can just grab the body contents I can manipulate it.

Comment: Did you try to use the JSON parser as I sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using express, you can setup a middleware to catch this kind of errors

```
router.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  if(error instanceof SyntaxError) {
    switch(error.type) {
      case 'entity.parse.failed':
        // JSON is incorrect
        break;
      default:
        // Some other kind of error happened
        break;
    }

    res.status(400).end();
  } else {
    next();
  }
})
```

Comment: Something I'm doing is causing the middleware not to get called. I have a separate routes.js file with one POST router defined. I threw the error capture in above the route, and I would think router.use with no route specified means it applies to everything...